# Multiple ListLogLogPlot from two data sets

Tags: plotting

I am trying to show the full plots from two set of data on the graph, but as can be seen the lower limit of one plot is chopped off[image]. How do you get full view of both plots, with x minimum placed at 0.02?

```
Show[ListLogLogPlot[data2, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Joined -> True, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Large], AxesOrigin -> {0.02, 0}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {Full, All}], 
   ListLogLogPlot[data1, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Joined -> True, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Large], AxesOrigin -> {0.02, 0}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {Full, All}]]
```

data1= {{0.020024338, 0.0006898460868074602}, {0.022380134, 
  0.0008222211281134352}, {0.024735928, 
  0.0009798403395959478}, {0.027091718, 
  0.0011277386823632257}, {0.029447506, 0.001287650013883181}, 
   {0.031803289, 0.0014408678900920552}, {0.034159069, 
  0.0016160163501166731}, {0.036514845, 
  0.0017849655926368134}, {0.038870616, 
  0.0019609711155541072}, {0.041226383, 0.002163665248453372}, 
   {0.043582144, 0.002348722618246531}, {0.0459379, 
  0.002494118081198361}, {0.048293651, 
  0.0027189360726542905}, {0.050649396, 
  0.002890344109549366}, {0.053005134, 0.00308609501146371}, 
   {0.055360866, 0.0032756176392236772}, {0.057716592, 
  0.0034527839522427227}, {0.06007231, 
  0.0036393851282367053}, {0.062428021, 
  0.003814914813351725}, {0.064783725, 0.003991495211267792}, 
   {0.06713942, 0.004193356042611242}, {0.069495108, 
  0.004347850320821656}, {0.071850787, 
  0.004558769934960127}, {0.074206457, 
  0.004709256362951678}, {0.076562119, 0.004907805739612362}, 
   {0.078917771, 0.005021310792831887}, {0.081273413, 
  0.005215178112302661}, {0.083629045, 
  0.005339973505995938}, {0.085984668, 
  0.005528800593303607}, {0.08834028, 0.005668827916130827}, 
   {0.090695881, 0.0057706688742881415}, {0.093051471, 
  0.005949966432781134}, {0.09540705, 
  0.00604459764249459}, {0.097762617, 
  0.006197882035914605}, {0.10011817, 0.006271995639457581}, 
   {0.10247372, 0.006405720497387288}, {0.10482925, 
  0.006479920911483725}, {0.10718476, 
  0.00660650821981006}, {0.10954027, 
  0.006672242838959252}, {0.11189576, 0.006817059539222547}, 
   {0.11425124, 0.006907264305529506}, {0.1166067, 
  0.007002603109893158}, {0.11896215, 
  0.007081107878571615}, {0.12131759, 
  0.007151235578737916}, {0.12367301, 0.007228141122266792}, 
   {0.12602842, 0.007292298578139804}, {0.12838381, 
  0.0073299493627207385}, {0.13073918, 
  0.00739858167168394}, {0.13309454, 
  0.007510978536398175}, {0.13544988, 0.00760847199922202}, 
   {0.13780521, 0.007544074863000653}, {0.14016052, 
  0.0076105707308896375}};

data2 = {{0.020024338, 0.007685848099917109}, {0.022380134, 
  0.008013449957524992}, {0.024735928, 
  0.008306098008526386}, {0.027091718, 
  0.008560896029885981}, {0.029447506, 0.00880745615391358}, 
   {0.031803289, 0.009248339043114036}, {0.034159069, 
  0.009782487939313599}, {0.036514845, 
  0.010345832941871655}, {0.038870616, 
  0.011113809369050385}, {0.041226383, 0.011874557973390829}, 
   {0.043582144, 0.012872539519762381}, {0.0459379, 
  0.013835602111955498}, {0.048293651, 
  0.014887746343237473}, {0.050649396, 
  0.015785394779266458}, {0.053005134, 0.0165642067516995}, 
   {0.055360866, 0.016999450787037237}, {0.057716592, 
  0.017014052764149582}, {0.06007231, 
  0.016734562545381238}, {0.062428021, 
  0.016069682185080734}, {0.064783725, 0.015031834901125234}, 
   {0.06713942, 0.013839656266037103}, {0.069495108, 
  0.01257969547079863}, {0.071850787, 
  0.011491569688389006}, {0.074206457, 
  0.010510929745291489}, {0.076562119, 0.009686346759612252}, 
   {0.078917771, 0.008863853826819992}, {0.081273413, 
  0.008156681447299127}, {0.083629045, 
  0.007561007783617579}, {0.085984668, 
  0.0070605580695412}, {0.08834028, 0.006621329915210725}, 
   {0.090695881, 0.006275814238247226}, {0.093051471, 
  0.006000914851069818}, {0.09540705, 
  0.0057212432986298856}, {0.097762617, 
  0.005553674274131074}, {0.10011817, 0.005357777593168054}, 
   {0.10247372, 0.005229874217954748}, {0.10482925, 
  0.005105247381949845}, {0.10718476, 
  0.005074708465411825}, {0.10954027, 
  0.0049336308402372795}, {0.11189576, 0.004871110936303876}, 
   {0.11425124, 0.004871859818927847}, {0.1166067, 
  0.0048258933894099075}, {0.11896215, 
  0.004768585775053847}, {0.12131759, 
  0.0047833895145830896}, {0.12367301, 0.004721254232423347}, 
   {0.12602842, 0.004760666810956435}, {0.12838381, 
  0.004693520058931346}, {0.13073918, 
  0.004739975744110606}, {0.13309454, 
  0.004693899534401102}, {0.13544988, 0.004672903298580988}, 
   {0.13780521, 0.004719793331953254}, {0.14016052, 
  0.004704144869921119}};

Comment: `PlotRange` is inherited from the first plot. You can do `Show[..., PlotRange -> All]` to force it to include both plots. Alternatively, instead of using `Show` to combine two plots, I would recommend just doing a single `ListLogLogPlot[{data1, data2}, ...]`.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
ListLogLogPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, 
     PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Joined -> True, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Large], AxesOrigin -> {0.02, 0}, 
     Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {Full, All}]
```

Comment: PlotRange->{0.02,0.14}  can be used to adjust the minimum x-point